# Finding the PDF after applying a transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> If the random variables $X$ and $Y$ have joint density function
> $$f_{XY}(x,y)=
> \begin{cases} 
>       \frac{xy}{96} & 0<x<4,1<y<5 \\
>       0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> , find the density function of $U=X+2Y$.
>
> **Ans:**
> $$g_U(u)=
> \begin{cases}
>       \frac{1}{2304}(u-2)^2(u-4) & 2<u<6 \\\\
>       \frac{1}{144}(3u-8) & 6<u<10 \\\\
>       \frac{1}{2304}(348u-u^3-2128) & 10<u<14 \\\\
>       0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$

I managed to get the expressions right except for $10<u<14$.
Here's what I did,

I let $u=x+2y$, $v=x$. Then

$$x=v, 0<v<4$$

$$y=\frac{u-v}{2}, v+2<u<v+10$$

with Jacobian $$J = \frac{1}{2}$$

Graphing this out, I saw that I could describe the region as three split regions, namely $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$.
$$R_1 = \{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2:2<u<6, 0<v<u-2\}$$
$$R_2 = \{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2:6<u<10, 0<v<4\}$$
$$R_3 = \{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2:10<u<14, 0<v<u-10\}$$
$$R = R_1 \cup R_2 \cup R_3$$

Then, the CDF would be:
$$F_U(u)=
\begin{cases}
      \int_2^u \int_0^{u-2} \frac{1}{192}v(u-v)|J| \,dv\,du & 2<u<6\\
      \int_6^u \int_0^{4} \frac{1}{192}v(u-v)|J|\,dv\,du & 6<u<10\\
      \int_{10}^u \int_0^{u-10} \frac{1}{192}v(u-v)|J|\,dv\,du & 10<u<14\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$F_U(u)=
\begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{2304}(\frac{1}{4}u^4-6u^2+16u)-\frac{1}{96} & 2<u<6\\
      \frac{1}{144}(\frac{3}{2}u^2-8u)-\frac{1}{12} & 6<u<10\\
      \frac{1}{2304}(\frac{1}{4}u^4-150u^2+2000u) & 10<u<14\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Differentiating to get $f_U(u)$ gives,
$$f_U(u)=
\begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{2304}(u-2)^2(u+4) & 2<u<6\\
      \frac{1}{144}(3u-8) & 6<u<10\\
      \frac{1}{2304}(u^3-300u+2000) & 10<u<14\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I'm not sure where I've went wrong with the third expression. The integral of the answer provided across all values of $u$ gives 1, which means the answer isn't wrong.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Looking at the support in the answer on $[2,14]$ and its divisions, I would guess the original question actually asked for $U=X+2Y$ and was mistyped here

Comment: @Henry Indeed it was a typo and the question asks for $U=X+2Y$.

Comment: Since you used change of variables, I wonder why you did not find the joint density of $(U,V)$ first and hence find the marginal density of $U$.

\\ Denoting the support by $S$ (which has to be worked out), joint density of $(U,V)$ would be

$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}\left(v,\frac{u-v}{2}\right)|J|\,\mathbf1_S$$

From here, $$f_U(u)=\int f_{U,V}(u,v)\,dv $$